# effects of a `const` as a template argument to a move constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Considering the following cases, what is the effect of adding a `const` as part of the template argument?

#### Case 1: `void func()` takes a parameter of type `T` by copy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T>
void func(T val_)
{
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
    std::cout<< "type of `val_` is `" << type_id_with_cvr< decltype(val_) >().pretty_name() << "`" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *f = new int(2);  

    func<int>(2);                // type of `val_` is `int` - OK
    func<int*>( f );             // type of `val_` is `int*` - OK
    func<const int*>( f );       // type of `val_` is `int const*` - OK
    func<const int* const>( f ); // type of `val_` is `int const* const` - OK
}
```

No questions for the first case... It's clear what is going on.

#### Case 2: `void func()` takes a parameter of type `T` by reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T>
void func(T &val_)
{
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
    std::cout<< "type of `val_` is `" << type_id_with_cvr< decltype(val_) >().pretty_name() << "`" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *f = new int(2);  

    func<int>(2);                // error - OK
    func<int*>( f );             // type of `val_` is `int*&` - OK
    func<const int*>( f );       // error: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'const int *&' - OK
    func<const int* const>( f ); // type of `val_` is `int const* const&` - ???
}
```

#### Case 3: `void func()` takes a parameter of type `T` by forwarding/universal reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T>
void func(T &&val_)
{
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
    std::cout<< "type of `val_` is `" << type_id_with_cvr< decltype(val_) >().pretty_name() << "`" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *f = new int(2);  

    func<int>(2);                // type of `val_` is `int&&` - OK
    func<int*>( f );             // error: no known conversion from 'int *' to 'int *&&' - OK
    func<const int*>( f );       // type of `val_` is `int const*&&` - ???
    func<const int* const>( f ); // type of `val_` is `int const* const&&` - ???
}
```

**Question #1:** In Case #2, why does `func<const int* const>( f );` get accepted just by adding the rhs `const`?

**Question #2:** In Case #3, why are the last two calls to `func` accepted just by adding a `const`?

**Question #3:** In Case #3, the benefit of using a forwarding reference is that if the function argument is an lvalue, then the type of `val_` will be an lvalue reference. If the argument is an rvalue, then the type of `val_` will be an rvalue. So, passing `f`, which is an lvalue, should make `T` an `int*&`. This is indeed the case when you don't specify the template argument `int*` at function call. However, when you specify the template argument `int*`, the result is a `int*&&`. Why?

Comment: We suppose to deduce arguments for forwarding/universal references.

Comment: and with case 1, you might handle case2/case3 with `func<int*&>`/`func<int*&&>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `f` is `int*`.  Only an `int*&` or `int* const&` can bind directly to that.

For case #2, `int*` and `int const*` are different types, so a reference to `int cont*` cannot bind directly to `f`.  A conversion from `int*` to `int const*` exists, but an lvalue-reference-to-non-const can't bind to the resulting object because it is an rvalue.  An lvalue-reference-to-const *can* bind to an rvalue though, so, since there's an implicit conversion from `int*` to `int const* const`, when you add `const` to the type a temporary `int const* const` can be created, and the reference can bind to it.

This is the same reason the following works:

```
void foo(const std::string& str) {}
int main() { foo("hello"); }
```

While the following doesn't:

```
void foo(std::string& str) {}
int main() { foo("hello"); }
```

---

For case #3, `int*` and `int const*` are different types.  Since implicit conversions exist from `int*` to both `int const*` and `int const* const`, temporary copies are created.  Those temporary copies are rvalues, so rvalue-references can bind to them no problem.  When you use `int*` as the template parameter, the type already matches, so no temporary copy gets made.  Since `f` is an lvalue, an rvalue-reference can't bind to it and you get an error.

---

To answer your last question that you edited in: forwarding references only arise if you let template parameters be deduced.  It's the template parameter deduction and reference collapsing rules that make them work, so you'll never get a forwarding reference if you specify explicit template parameters.

For example, given the following function template:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& obj) {}
```

If you pass an lvalue of type `int` (i.e. `foo(some_int_var)`), `T` will be deduced to be `int&`, so the type of `obj` is `int& &&`.  After the reference collapsing rules are applied, that collapses to`int&`: an lvalue-reference-to-int.  On the other hand, if you pass an rvalue of type `int` (i.e. `foo(42)`), `T` will be deduced to be `int`, so the type of `obj` will be `int&&`: rvalue-reference-to-int.

Comment: It took me some time to understand the first bit about case #2, but I'm still a bit fuzzy about the implicit conversion stuff. In the first part of your answer, you say *"a temporary `const int *` can't be created because an lvalue-reference-to-non-const can't bind to an rvalue"*, but in the second part of your answer, you say *"implicit conversions exist from `int*` to both `const int *` and `const int * const`, temporary copies are created."*. What's the difference? Could you please re-word that part?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Reworded that part.  The conversion results in an anonymous temporary object aka an rvalue.  The conversion exists, but that's not sufficient in case #2 since the lvalue-reference-to-non-const can't bind to the resulting object.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that forwarding references arise only with type deduction and the second part now makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In case #2, the first question should be: why is `func<const int *>(f)` bad? After all, usually you can use an `int *` where a `const int *` is wanted. The reason why it fails is that even though an `int *` is-a `const int *` (i.e., a thing you can dereference to get an `int` is a thing you can dereference to get a `const int`), a *reference* to an `int *` is not a reference to a `const int *` because you can assign "through" it. If you were allowed to call `func<const int *>(f)` then some different version of `func` could e.g. assign something that *really is* a `const int *` to `f`, after which you'd be able to modify what it points to, which would be Bad.

And now it should be obvious why the second `const` fixes it: you can't change the value of `f` by passing it by `const` reference.

Case #3 is somewhat similar. Again, the first question to ask isn't why your third and fourth cases work but why your second case fails. It fails because you aren't allowed to take an rvalue reference (`&&`) to an lvalue (a thing with a name, like `f`). Why not? Because one of the reasons for these things is to be able to get *different* behaviour depending on whether the thing being passed is a temporary (and hence safe to clobber) or not, and the way that's done is to forbid conversion of an lvalue of type `T` to an rvalue reference of type `T &&`. (So then you can write one function that takes a `T &` and another that takes a `T &&`, and make the latter do the more efficient clobbery thing.)

But just about anything you do to that lvalue will stop it being an lvalue and make the invocation of `func` legal again. For instance, you could add 0 to it. Or you could cast it to a different type. And, aha!, this is what is happening in your third and fourth examples in case #3: what's being passed to `func` is in effect not `f` itself but something like `const_cast<const int *>(f)`, and that's no longer an lvalue and all is well.

Comment: I like your explanation in the first part of the answer, which helps to understand the results from case #2. But your explanation about the 3rd case is not very clear. The benefit of using a forwarding reference is that if you pass an lvalue as an argument, the type will be an lvalue reference. So, passing `f`, which is an lvalue, should make `T` an `int*&`. And this is indeed the case when you don't specify the template argument `int*` at function call. However, when you specify the template argument `int*`, the result is a `int*&&`. Why? [example](https://rextester.com/OFG74479)

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos: As you noted, when you allow `T` to be inferred, it becomes `int*&`.This is different from the `T&&` argument becoming `int*&` (although it does).  It would be very strange for `T` in the next case to be `int*&` when you explicitly provided `int*`.  I presume you are not confused by that.  And then the `T&&` parameter becomes `int*&&` when `T` is `int*`,  This follows directly from the reference-collapsing rules.  When you specify `int*` there is nowhere for an lvalue reference to appear -- `T` is not one, and neither is the parameter type `T&&`.